# How to override the calling functionality of forgot password using azure active directory b2c

Tags: c#, azure, exception, passwords, azure-ad-b2c

I am using **Azure Active Directory B2C** for sign-in/sign-up policy in a **Xamarin** application.

But when I am clicking on the ***forgot password*** link on my page, B2C is redirecting back to the application with an error message.

> Exception: `Microsoft.Identity.Client.MsalServiceException:
>   'AADB2C90118: The user has forgotten their password. Correlation ID:
>   1587ecf1-90f6-42cf-99ad-44b3bdf60eb5 Timestamp: 2017-12-14 13:21:58Z'

I can capture this exception and I'm able to then reset the password using following code:

Note: `_azureAdB2COptions` is a model class

```
if (ex.Message.Contains("AADB2C90118"))
{
    try
    {
        var scopes = _azureAdB2COptions.Scopes.Split(' ');
        AuthenticationResult ar = await  _publicClientApplication.AcquireTokenAsync(scopes, (IUser)null, UIBehavior.SelectAccount, string.Empty, null, _azureAdB2COptions.AuthorityPasswordReset, uiParent);
    }
    catch (Exception exp)
    {
        await DisplayAlert("Status", "Password reset: " + exp.Message, "Close");
    }
}
```

[image: Exception screenshot]

Can someone help me to capture the forgot password "clicked event" and redirect to the password reset policy?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [UI customization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-ui-customization) feature to customize the page. On that, you can use CSS to hide the forgot password link added by B2C, and create your own link that sends an authorization request to forgot password.

There's a future feature that will also allow you to run JavaScript on these customized pages. Once that is available, you will be able to hook up click and similar events on the client.